# GDB, signals and SIG_IGN

Tags: c, gdb, signals

Setting a signal handler as `SIG_IGN` ignores the signal while running the program normally but not while running it through gdb.

I'm creating a timer using `timer_create` and `timer_settime` functions. I don't want to use a signal handler (i.e a function) to handle the signals generated by this timer. I decided to use `sigwait` and wait for `SIGALRM`. I set the handler for `SIGALRM` as `SIG_IGN` and used `sigwait`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define ISTRUE(x) (x != 0)
#define bool int

int main() {
    struct itimerspec timer_spec;
    struct sigevent sig_event;
    timer_t timer_id;
    sigset_t sig_set;


    timer_spec.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    timer_spec.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    timer_spec.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    timer_spec.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;

    sig_event.sigev_signo = SIGALRM;
    sig_event.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;


    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);


    /* Create the timer */
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sig_event, &timer_id);
    timer_settime(timer_id, 0, &timer_spec, NULL);

    sigemptyset(&sig_set);
    sigaddset(&sig_set, SIGALRM);

    int signal = 0;
    bool running = TRUE;

    while (ISTRUE(running)) {
        sigwait(&sig_set, &signal);
        switch(signal){
            case SIGINT:
                printf("Interrupt received.. exiting\n");
                running = 0;
                break;
            case SIGALRM:
                printf("Ticked\n");
                break;
        }
        printf("Sleeping\n");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

While debugging the application in my IDE (CLion) as well as using gdb from the shell, the program functioned as expected. `SIGALRM` was not being ignored, which led me to believe that what I was doing was right. However, running the application normally, `sigwait` never returns.

I later realized that this was because the signal was being ignored and I needed to block the signal (using `sigprocmask` or similar) and set it to a pending state.

Why does, while debugging, the signal get passed through? Is this supposed to happen? What am I missing?

Comment: It appears ptrace seems to be causing this somehow because the behavior can also be observed when the program is run under `strace`. Looks like an interesting Linux quirk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into the `handle` gdb command:

```
(gdb) handle SIGALRM
Signal        Stop      Print   Pass to program Description
SIGALRM       No        No      Yes             Alarm clock
(gdb) handle SIGALRM ignore
Signal        Stop      Print   Pass to program Description
SIGALRM       No        No      No              Alarm clock
(gdb) help handle
... read it ;-) ...
```

As mentioned in the manpage of `ptrace(2)` (which `gdb` is using):

> While  being  traced, the tracee will stop each time a signal is delivered, even if the signal is being ignored.

Comment: I had tried `handle SIGALRM ignore` before posting the question. However, there was no difference. Also, the manpage says: **tracee will stop each time a signal is delivered** However, this does not explain why the signal itself is put as 'pending'. Or, am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's true that is it's not possible to emulate the behavior of the untraced process under gdb or other program using ptrace. That's because a ptrace-d process will be **a)** stopped each time a signal is sent to it, even if the signal is ignored, and **b)** the restarting of the tracee by the tracer will cause any blocking system call to return to userland -- and not all system calls will be restarted. If the signal was in `sigtimedwait()`'s mask, `sigtimedwait()` will return it, otherwise it will return -1 and set `errno` to `EINTR`.

Comment: It's the glibc library function `sigwait(3)` which is restarting the `sigtimedwait(2)` syscall used to implement it, confusing things. You can easily check all this by removing the `sigaddset` call from your program and running it under `strace`. There's a section in the `signal(7)` manpage on Linux about this: "Interruption of system calls and library functions by stop signals".